No display of data in LiveWire
I'm attempting to create a Multi-Step Appointment Booking feature. However, I'm encountering an issue with Livewire and Flowbite.
I have this code in my Blade file for displaying a carousel of dates:
    @if ($currentStep == 2)

    <div id="controls-carousel" class="w-1/2 mb-5" data-carousel="static">
        <div class="flex mb-5">
            <button type="button"
                class="z-30 flex items-center justify-center h-full cursor-pointer group focus:outline-none"
                data-carousel-prev>
                <span
                    class="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-10 h-10 rounded group-hover:bg-gray-200 dark:group-hover:bg-gray-800/60 group-focus:ring-4 group-focus:ring-white dark:group-focus:ring-gray-800/70 group-focus:outline-none">
                    <svg class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-800 rtl:rotate-180" aria-hidden="true"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 6 10">
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M5 1 1 5l4 4" />
                    </svg>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </span>
            </button>
            <button type="button"
                class="z-30 flex items-center justify-center h-full cursor-pointer group focus:outline-none"
                data-carousel-next>
                <span
                    class="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-10 h-10 rounded group-hover:bg-gray-200 dark:group-hover:bg-gray-800/60 group-focus:ring-4 group-focus:ring-white dark:group-focus:ring-gray-800/70 group-focus:outline-none">
                    <svg class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-800 rtl:rotate-180" aria-hidden="true"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 6 10">
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="m1 9 4-4-4-4" />
                    </svg>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="relative overflow-hidden rounded-lg h-20">
            @foreach ($schedules->chunk(7) as $chunk)
                <div class="hidden duration-700 ease-in-out grid grid-cols-7 gap-2" data-carousel-item>
                    @foreach ($chunk as $schedule)
                    <div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-center bg-white rounded-full border cursor-pointer">
                        <div class="text-gray-500">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($schedule->start)->format('D') }}</div>
                        <div class="text-gray-700 font-bold text-2xl">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($schedule->start)->format('d') }}</div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endif

The problem arises when I place this code within @if ($currentStep == 1) and load the page; the carousel displays perfectly without any issues. However, when I place the code within @if ($currentStep == 2), upon opening the page and clicking on the next step button, the function $this->currentStep++ runs in my Livewire component. I can see the step 2 form, but the carousel fails to function properly. I only see the buttons, and the data-carousel-item is not being displayed.
i want to see carousel in step 2

What does the full blade-view look like? It might be that you have multiple root-elements, although they might be conditional. Try wrapping your entire view in one big div.

Yes its all in one big div but the problem is not here , Actually, I found that in Livewire, anywhere I have a data attribute or JavaScript inside an @if statement, it doesn't work at all and i dont know if there is a solution for that or not

Are you using Livewire v2 or v3?

Also keep in mind that if you have any other JavaScript that changes HTML elements or state, you need wire:ignore. This is documented in the Livewire docs
